# SQL - comparing date parameter to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In a SQL Server table, I have a field named Timestamp, which is a 'datetime' field. On a screen I have created, a user will pass in a date (no time), and I need to return all the records for that date.

Just doing Timestamp = @Date doesn't seem to work unless the time in the field is 00:00:00. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You better compare date without timestamp. Otherwise.. How to get result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server 2008, you can use the `DATE` datatype.

Do a comparison between

```
 CAST(Timestamp AS DATE) = @Date
```

That should work and look just at the date - no time portion.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should think about the data from a specific date as data that falls in a range, not at a single point in time. So ideally your query should use a range, such as:

```
WHERE [Timestamp] >= @Date
AND [Timestamp] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date)
```

In this case, luckily, the optimizer is smart and will still use an index if you use `CONVERT(DATE, [timestamp])` against the column. However in a lot of cases you need to be careful because this will often make your clause non-sargable.

PS `Timestamp` is a horrible column name. It's a data type in SQL Server which has nothing to do with date or time.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique for truncating the time part off a datetime value is to use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) and [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) functions. In your example it would be used like this to truncate the time part of the Timestamp field.

```
WHERE @DateEntered = DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Timestamp))
```

Bascially it's taking the datetime value and finding the name of days since "the date represented by 0" (for lack of a better description) and then adding that number of days back. This effectively truncates time part.